# Частица и омонимичные части речи

Tags: части-речи, частица

В предложении «А какая в лесу тишина!» слово «какая» - частица или всё-таки местоимение?

Answer (score 1):

В толковых словарях функция частицы для этого слова **не указывается**, но это все-таки толковые словари, а не грамматические справочники. Я же думаю, что усилительное и вполне определенное семантическое значение частицы  (восхищение или пренебрежение) в таких предложениях явно просматривается.

Я приведу цитату из достаточно авторитетного источника, где объясняется ситуация со словом КАКОЙ. https://studopedia.ru/2_80475_chastitsi.html

«С другой стороны, местоимение КАКОЙ в восклицательных предложениях выступает, как и ЧТО ЗА, в роли **усилительной частицы** (обычно эта функция отмечается только для слова КАК), например: Ну что за шейка, что за глазки! Рассказывать — так, право, сказки! Какие перышки! Какой носок! (Крылов). Поскольку слово КАКОЙ сохраняет изменение по родам, числам и падежам, вряд ли его можно считать частицей в такой же мере, как и другие усилительные слова. Перед нами типичный **переходный случай** в системе частей речи».

Таким образом,  мы можем считать, что  слово КАКОЙ не относится постоянно    **к классу частиц,** но оно способно в определенных случаях приобретать **значение  и функцию** частицы.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно местоимение, так как «какая» согласовывается с «тишина» по роду, числу, падежу. Не бывает омонимичных частей речи, это какой-то кристальный бред.

Comment: А вы сами-то что пишете? Почитайте, например: "Омонимичные части речи являются результатом трансформации (перехода) слов из одной части речи в другую".  https://pandia.ru/text/78/356/1392.php  И вопрос о возможности перехода  местоимения КАКОЙ в частицу тоже спорный.  Какая в лесу тишина! Какая там тишина с этит дачниками. Во втором предложении это частица (со  значением пренебрежения).

Comment: Часть речи — это класс слов. По отношению к чему может быть омонимичен класс слов? По отношению к другому классу слов? Если какой-то идиот-грамотей написал это, то это не превращается в менее кристальный бред. По поводу этих предложений. Нет, в этих предложениях «какая» — местоимение. Частицы не согласовываются по РОДАМ, ПАДЕЖАМ И ЧИСЛАМ. В следующих предложениях: «Ты отдохнул?» «— Какое там! Как тут отдохнешь с этими детьми.» — сочетание «какое там» является междометьем.

Comment: «Какие там видеоигры с этой работой, я поспать не успеваю» — предложение как у вас, но местоимение «какая» изменило число.

Comment: Самое время вам начать удалять свои сообщения, как обычно. Если поставите плюсик, я удалю и свои сообщения, Sharon.